# CS50 pset 1 cash issue : code returns abnormal huge amounts

Tags: c, cs50

I just took the CS50 course and am struggling with the Pset 1. Here is my code :

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int get_cents(void);
int calculate_quarters(int cents);
int calculate_dimes(int cents);
int calculate_nickels(int cents);
int calculate_pennies(int cents);

int main(void)
{
    // Ask how many cents the customer is owed
    int cents = get_cents();

    // Calculate the number of quarters to give the customer
    int quarters = calculate_quarters(cents);
    cents = cents - quarters * 25;

    // Calculate the number of dimes to give the customer
    int dimes = calculate_dimes(cents);
    cents = cents - dimes * 10;

    // Calculate the number of nickels to give the customer
    int nickels = calculate_nickels(cents);
    cents = cents - nickels * 5;

    // Calculate the number of pennies to give the customer
    int pennies = calculate_pennies(cents);
    cents = cents - pennies * 1;

    // Sum coins
    int coins = quarters + dimes + nickels + pennies;

    // Print total number of coins to give the customer
    printf("%i\n", quarters);
}

int get_cents(void)
{
    int owed;
    do
    {
        owed = get_int("Change owed: ");
    } while (owed<=0);

    return owed;
}

int calculate_quarters(int cents)
{
    int n;
    while (cents <= 25)
    {
        n++;
        cents = cents - 25;
    }

    return n;
}

int calculate_dimes(int cents)
{
    int n;
    while (cents <= 10)
    {
        n++;
        cents = cents - 10;
    }

    return n;
}

int calculate_nickels(int cents)
{
    int n;
    while (cents <= 5)
    {
        n++;
        cents = cents - 5;
    }

    return n;
}

int calculate_pennies(int cents)
{
    int n;
    while (cents <= 1)
    {
        n++;
        cents = cents - 1;
    }

    return n;
}
```

The code returns huge amounts like "277258257".The issue is on the functions but I can't figure out what it is. When I use these same while loops in the main function instead of creating functions, it works perfectly (but then, it doesn't meet the exercise requirement as the CS50 bot also checks if these functions are present in the code).

P.S : sorry for my English, my main language is French and I sometimes say things weirdly. If anything that I said does not make sense please tell me.

Comment: As a beginner I recommend `#include <assert.h>`  and `assert`ing each step of your problem, you will see which part fails when the assertion fails(along with the line number and statement).  Also don't forget to add a return statement to your main, it may compile properly on your computer but it might not on somebody else's.

Comment: Compiling your source code with warnings enabled reports `coins` is not used and `n` is used without being initialized. Enable warnings in your compiler and elevate warnings to errors.  With Clang, start with `-Wmost -Werror`. With GCC, start with `-Wall -Werror`. With MSVC, start with `/W3 /WX`.

Comment: @Dmitry: Per C 2018 5.1.2.2.3 1, no `return` statement in needed in `main`. If a hosted C implementation does not work with no `return` statement in `main`, it does not conform to the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You're right, objectively it's not a big deal, it usually just means one less warning on certain compilers such as turbo c. I just find it better to be consistent to avoid getting into a mental state thinking that functions return 0 by default for all int returning functions(which doesn't even give a warning on many compilers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following

```
int n;
/* ... */
n++
```

`n` is *uninitialized*, containing an *indeterminate* value. Sometimes referred to as a *garbage value*, this value is effectively random. Utilizing this value in `n++` invokes [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

Initialize each variable.

```
int n = 0;
```

---

Each `while` loop for calculating the coins is using the wrong operator. Change

```
while (cents <= 25)
```

to

```
while (cents >= 25)
```

And the same with the others.

---

`coins` is unused. Change

```
printf("%i\n", quarters);
```

to

```
printf("%i\n", coins);
```

Comment: Yeaaah ! I just saw that I was using the wrong operators in my while loops. Thank you very much!